NodeJS Warning: DeprecationWarning: fs.Stats constructor is deprecated
I have installed node v22.2.0, and working on AdonisJS project.
When I execute node ace I get the following warning:
(node:236312) [DEP0180] DeprecationWarning: fs.Stats constructor is deprecated.
(Use `node --trace-deprecation ...` to show where the warning was created)

After running with --trace-deprecation I get:
> node --trace-deprecation ace list
(node:236392) [DEP0180] DeprecationWarning: fs.Stats constructor is deprecated.
    at Object.createResolve (/data/apps/adonis-backend/node_modules/ts-node/dist-raw/node-internal-modules-esm-resolve.js:146:25)
    at /data/apps/adonis-backend/node_modules/ts-node/src/index.ts:1494:7
    at Object.onceFn [as getNodeEsmResolver] (/data/apps/adonis-backend/node_modules/ts-node/src/util.ts:166:13)
    at createEsmHooks (/data/apps/adonis-backend/node_modules/ts-node/src/esm.ts:125:51)
    at Object.registerAndCreateEsmHooks (/data/apps/adonis-backend/node_modules/ts-node/src/esm.ts:118:10)
    at file:///data/apps/adonis-backend/node_modules/ts-node/esm.mjs:8:7
    at ModuleJob.run (node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:262:25)
    at async ModuleLoader.import (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:475:24)
    at async Hooks.register (node:internal/modules/esm/hooks:150:26)
    at async MessagePort.handleMessage (node:internal/modules/esm/worker:255:18)

What should I do?

ts-node/dist-raw/node-internal-modules-esm-resolve.js is using that deprecated-but-still-working constructor. There's an upstream issue about this.
You should do nothing, except maybe  that issue, or write a PR in ts-node to fix it.

I also had this error. I solved it by installing version 20 of nodejs

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
